# Выбор и отображение нескольких файлов в QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtreeview

Создана форма в *Qt Designer*. Есть `QTreeView` с подгрузкой файловой системы (извиняюсь за не правильное выражение, надеюсь понятно).

Как выделить несколько файлов, к примеру с зажатым клавишей <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и получить пути к ним?

Хотелось бы по директориям перемещаться, а не программно задавать её.

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете перемещаться по директориям.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.treeview  = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.listview  = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listview2 = QtWidgets.QListView()

        # установить нужный каталог
        path = QtCore.QDir.rootPath()
        #path = QtCore.QDir.currentPath()
        #path = "E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5" 

        # dirModel
        self.dirModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.dirModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.AllDirs)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.dirModel)
        self.treeview.setRootIndex(self.dirModel.index(path))
        self.treeview.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_dir)

        # fileModel
        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))
        self.listview.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.on_selectionChanged)
        self.listview.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.listview2.setModel(self.model)
        self.listview2.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self.treeview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview2)

    def on_selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        roles = (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, 
                 QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole,
                 QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole,
                 QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        for ix in selected.indexes():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(ix.data())
            for role in roles:
                it.setData(ix.data(role), role)
            self.model.appendRow(it)
        filter_role = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole
        for ix in deselected.indexes():
            for index in self.model.match(ix.parent(), filter_role, ix.data(filter_role), -1, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly):
                self.model.removeRow(index.row())

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        print("on_clicked: itemIndex=`{}`, itemText=`{}`"
                           "".format(item.index().row(), item.text()))

    def on_clicked_dir(self, index):
        path = self.dirModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.setRootPath(path))                           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При этом скрытые файлы и папки не отображаются (в Linux точно). Как реализовать их отображение?

Comment: @КиберЛегион в данном вопросе никто не спрашивал о скрытых файлах и скрытых папках. Я обратил внимание на ваш вопрос, который вы задали и попробую в нем дать ответ для вас.

Answer (score 2):

[Пример добавления выделенных файлов (и папок).](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/47b5b4ff084ab8b173118bd4c1aa6425517d7366/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__QFileSystemModel__append_selected_files_and_dirs.py#L14) При клике на кнопку `Добавить!` в список справа будут добавлены те пути, что были выделены.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QListWidget, QPushButton, QSplitter,
    QVBoxLayout, QApplication
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        path = QDir.rootPath()

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(path)

        self.tree_view = QTreeView()
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree_view.setSelectionMode(QTreeView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self._on_selection_changed)

        self.list_files = QListWidget()

        self.button_add = QPushButton('Добавить!')
        self.button_add.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self._on_add)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(self.tree_view)
        splitter.addWidget(self.list_files)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_add)

    def _on_selection_changed(self, selected, deselected):
        has = self.tree_view.selectionModel().hasSelection()
        self.button_add.setEnabled(has)

    def _on_add(self):
        for row in self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            path = self.model.filePath(row)
            self.list_files.addItem(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Если нужно чтобы только файлы можно было добавлять, нужно в `_on_selection_changed` сделать проверку -- что выделен хотя бы один файл, а в `_on_add`, соответственно, обрабатывать только файлы.