# Файловый менеджер на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую идею: 
Файловый менеджер с возможностью множественного выбора файлов, папок, а так же отображением скрытых файлов и папок (Linux, Windows).

Что требуется:

1. Отображение файловой системы, в том числе скрытых файлов и папок (*Linux*, *Windows*).
2. Множественный выбор файлов и папок. (С помощью чекбокса и/или другими доступными средствами).
3. Кнопка "Удалить", с функцией удаления выбранных файлов/папок.

В *PyQt5* недавно, строго не судите. Нашел что-то типа:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import (
QApplication, QWidget, QSplitter, QTreeView, QTextEdit,
QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout, QDir
)
import os


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())

        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index('/'))
        self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self._on_double_clicked)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()

        splitter = QSplitter()
        splitter.addWidget(self.tree)
        splitter.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        splitter.setSizes([50, 200])

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_double_clicked(self, index):
        file_name = self.model.filePath(index)

        with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    win = MyWidget()
    win.resize(600, 400)
    win.show()

    app.exec()
```

Но в итоге:

1. Не отображаются скрытые файлы и папки.
2. Нет множественного выбора
3. Не знаю как отображать файловую систему независимо от платформы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не очень хорошо задавать много вопросов одновременно.
2. Вы никак не показали свои попытки решения данных вопросов.

А теперь по сути:

- **Не отображаются скрытые файлы и папки.**

`QFileSystemModel Class` - предоставляет модель данных для локальной файловой системы.

`QFileSystemModel::setFilter(QDir::Filters filters)` - устанавливает фильтр модели каталога на указанный фильтрами.
Обратите внимание, что фильтр, который вы устанавливаете, всегда должен включать значение 
перечисления `QDir::AllDirs`, иначе `QFileSystemModel` не сможет прочитать структуру каталогов.

`QDir Class` - обеспечивает доступ к структурам каталогов и их содержимому.

`QDir::Filter`  - описывает опции фильтрации.
Значение фильтра задается путем объединения значений из следующего списка с использованием побитового оператора ИЛИ.
Смотрите здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum

Т.о. чтобы отображались скрытые файлы и папки вам нужно:

```
self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
self.dirModel.setFilter(
    # ... |
    QDir.AllDirs | 
    QDir.Files | 
    QDir.Hidden     # <--- Список скрытых файлов (в Unix файлы начинаются с ".").
)
```

**- Нет множественного выбора:**

как вариант решения здесь [Выбор нескольких файлов в treeview pyqt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906987/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-treeview-pyqt)

Comment: Вопрос один. Состоит из нескольких подпунктов для удобства. Странный форум, на других все проще и удобнее. Ваш ответ уже не актуален. Нашел решение самостоятельно. Попыток не предоставил?) Абсолютно неудобный, долгий и бесполезный форум.

Comment: @КиберЛегион это не форум, это подразделение крупной зарубежной сети, для вопросов по проблемам программирования и ответов на них. Человек потратил время, дал Вам развернутый ответ. причем обратите что в Вашем вопросе нет вопроса.